# Is there a drag-n-drop SVG to PDF converter?

Tags: pdf, file-conversion

I use Inkscape quite a bit to produce presentations. Since Inkscape doesn't handle multiple pages, I end up with a lot of individual .svg files. I then have to open each one and 'save as' a PDF to then import them all into preview. Which is kind of a pain.

Ideally preview would support SVG, but until then, I was wondering if there was a native OSX app I could use to just drop SVG files onto and have it spit out PDF versions. Anyone know if it exists?

Answer (score 3):

If you have inkscape installed you can use its command line interface to convert svg to pdf.

```
/Applications/Inkscape.app/Contents/Resources/bin/inkscape test.svg --export-pdf test.pdf
```

Using Automator you'll be able to make a simple app that accept drag'n'drop.

Look for `run shell script`.

Answer (score 1):

I used Automator to create an app that converts multiple JPGs into a single PDF. And, frankly, I don't know how to use Automator or AppleScript barely at all so if I could manage it, you probably can, too. Do a Google search for applescript + convert image OR pdf and you'll likely run across the same bits of script I did.

Comment: Automator appears to be the answer. Alas, I'm lost. I did find this example: http://www.faq-mac.com/tutoriales/automator-convertir-archivos-svg-pdf-juan-dios-santander/50782 but I just get 'an error has occurred in your script' when I run it. Thanks for the lead, though. Off to investigate more...

Comment: SVG is not a supported image format for MacOS's Automator commands (or CoreGraphics generally).