# Merge svg files into PDF

Tags: pdf, macos

I have a directory of about 1000 svg files in svgz extension, which resembles a textbook. An example of the svg files can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UOO2pnh-qp5A0aSDChWC6HJbzpGYKeS5).How would I merge the files into a PDF while preserving as much quality as possible?

As you can see in this image[image], the PDF rendering of the svg is incomplete, but a quicklook view or opening it in chrome renders it completely. Google Drive preview also does not render it completely.

Comment: Are both sets of files (SVG *and* HTML) required for the PDF, or only one set? If both, how do they need to get combined? What are you using to view/render them currently? Are you looking for a ready-made solution or do you have some coding experience so you could create something once you know which tools to use?

Comment: Also, I just had a look at the files: neither the SVG nor the HTML files as such provide enough information, it seems that parts are missing.

Comment: From what I see the information in the SVG and HTML files is not enough to reconstruct the content. You can easily check this by opening some of the HTML files in a browser

Comment: There are pages where you only have the html, and some where you only have the svg. And where you have both I don‘t see how they relate together

Comment: You can check this yourself, by looking at the source. Take page 173 for instance, the HTML file doesn't reference the SVG at all, so I assume that there is some Javascript or another (unknown) way to combine this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on nohillside's answer and Matthieu Riegler's [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/142430/is-there-a-drag-n-drop-svg-to-pdf-converter?rq=1), this is my solution:

```
cd /
for i in /path/to/folder/*.svgz
    /Applications/Inkscape.app/Contents/Resources/bin/inkscape $i --export-pdf $i.pdf
end
cd /path/to/folder
launchctl limit maxfiles 10240 10240
ulimit -n 10240
pdfunite *.pdf book.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the information in the SVG files is enough to rebuild the book (which isn't, as far as I can see):

Install Homebrew by visiting [brew.sh](https://brew.sh/) and following the instructions, and then run

```
brew install imagemagick
brew install poppler

cd SVG-Folder
for i in *.svgz; do magick convert "$i" "${i%%svgz}pdf"; done
pdfunite *.pdf book.pdf
```

Comment: This did not work for me. See the updated question.